How to handle very long MPEG-DASH VOD playlist
We've developed a NVR system that records h24 multiple cameras. For each camera there is a dedicated folder with this structure:
Camera-001
  -> 2024
    -> 01
      -> 01
        -> 00:00
            -> ... chunks and mpd ...
        -> 01:00
            -> ... chunks and mpd ...
        ...

Note that by aziendal policy, each camera has a minimum retain time of 6 months (some special case can go to 1 year).
Now, we want to play the entire streaming of a single camera like it was a single unique file. In order to do that, I think, we need to create another mpd at root level that links (using xlink for example) with mpd contained in single folders.
This is the right approach? Do you have some hint ? If the strategy of recording in subfolders isn't right, we can also change it.
